# Convergence of a complex series for some values of z

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Find all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ for which the series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-i)^nz^n$$ converges.

I'm not really sure where to start. I know that most convergence tests for real numbers also  hold for complex series as well! Do I have to use one of those for this? Please help!

Comment: treat it like a geometric series and write necessary condition for converging a geometric series

Comment: Calculate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (-i)^nz^n=0$, then use that absolute convergence implies converge

Comment: Hint: apply the ratio test. That tells you about everywhere except on the circle whose radius is the radius of convergence.

Answer (score 1):

This is a power series with term $a_n=(-i)^n$. 

Thus we compute it's convergance radius $R=\frac1L$ where $L= \limsup |a_n|^{\frac1n}$.
$$L= \limsup {|(-i)|^{n}}^{\frac1n}=1$$
So $R=1$ and it converges  $\forall$ $|z|<1$ and diverges $\forall |z|>1$. 

But we also need to examine what happens for $|z|=1$, that is, on the perimeter of the unit circle. 

***EDIT*** 

We have for $|z|=1$
$$|(-i)^nz^n|=1\rightarrow1$$
so, as Did remarked at the comments below, the general term of the series does not converge to zero so it does not converge on the perimeter of the unit circle either.

Comment: "so it converges on the perimeter of the unit circle" No.

Comment: @Did It doesn't? Could you please explain why? Are the preceding arguments correct at least?

Comment: Because the general term of the series does not converge to zero, which is a necessary condition for the series to converge.

Comment: @Did So it does not converge on the perimeter but the rest are correct I presume? If so I will edit it accordingly and obviously cite you..

Comment: @Did Thank you for your correction. I edited the answer as suggested.

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake Great answer thanks for your help!

Comment: @fitz My pleasure! I am glad it helped.. PS You can accept it as a answer if you wish!